# Cannot connect java client to cassandra with password authentication enabled

Tags: authentication, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have a default install of Datastax enterprise on my macbook. I was able to create my keyspace and setup all my applications including using solr.

I am trying to develop a set of steps to turn on password authentication for our dev cluster.

Thus far I have updated `/usr/local/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml` and changed the following properties:

```yaml
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
authorizer: CassandraAuthorizer
```

I restarted the node and could login and query my keyspace using cqlsh:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

At this point I tried setting the Credentials on the Session builder:
Host is: `cassandra.host=localhost`

```java
Session session = keyspaceToSessionMap.get(keyspace);
    if( session == null){
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts)
                .withCredentials(username, password)
                //.withSSL()
                .build();
        session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
        keyspaceToSessionMap.put(keyspace,session);
    }
```

I could not successfully connect however. So I added a new user and was able to again login via cqlsh but still cannot get the Java driver to connect.

```
cqlsh -u username -p password
Connected to LocalCluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.8.689 | DSE 4.7.3 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

I am using `'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse:2.1.9'` via gradle for the driver.

I always get the following stack trace and through debugging can see the username and password are set properly:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host localhost/127.0.0.1:9042: Username and/or password are incorrect
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:376)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$8.apply(Connection.java:346)
```

This seems like it should be simple but I am stumped.

My dependencies graph in relation to cassandra driver contains the following:

```
+--- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-dse:2.1.9
|    \--- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.9 -> 2.1.8
|         +--- io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.27.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.27.Final
|         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-common:4.0.27.Final
|         |    +--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final
|         |    |    \--- io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.27.Final (*)
|         |    \--- io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.27.Final
|         |         \--- io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.27.Final (*)
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1 -> 18.0
|         \--- com.codahale.metrics:metrics-core:3.0.2
|              \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 -> 1.7.12
```

I created the following test which passes.

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("localhost")
                    .withCredentials("username", "password")
                    //.withSSL()
                    .build();
            Session session = cluster.connect("keyspace");
            Assert.assertNotNull(session);
```

The only difference I can tell between the two is that "localhost" is now a constant rather than an array of size 1.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete code example?  Everything you have provided seems correct to me, but maybe there is some nuance in the code that might reveal the problem.

Answer (score 9):

Found I had a trailing whitespace and that was the root cause.

```java
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts)
                .withCredentials(username.trim(), password.trim())
                //.withSSL()
                .build();
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it!  Thanks for sharing the solution, had me worried for a moment that there might have been a bug in the driver :)